# Javascript is working in the chrome console but its not working on Google Tag Manager (GTM)

Tags: javascript, schema, google-tag-manager, google-chrome-console

i have written a JS code to dynamically post a schema, the code is working on my computer and its working on firefox consol, sometimes its working on chrome console but its not working on Google Tag Manager, why?

i have checked the allow document.write check box and when i check the preview mode it shows the the tag is fired but the code inside the tag is plain, meaning its not executed, and when i submit and go check on live site, there is nothing! but i can still see the json code in the console

this is what is inside the HTML tag and the trigger is all pages (just to make sure)

How can i make this code work with GTM?

`

```
<script>

window.onload = function() {   
     
        var featured_div = document.getElementById("featured")
        var bigTitle = document.getElementById("bigtitle1")
        var items = featured_div.querySelectorAll(".lower")
        var schema = {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "Article",
        "@id":window.location.href + "/#article",
        "text" : "ash",
          "about": {
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "@type": "Place",
            "@id": "place",
            "name": document.querySelector(".hero-titulo").innerText,
            "image": " ",
             "publicAccess": true,
             "sameAs": [
             "https://www.louvre.fr/en",
             "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvre"
      ],
            "address": "Paris, France",
            "additionalType": "Museum"
    },
          "mainEntityOfPage": {
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "@type": "WebPage",
            "@id": window.location.href,
            "mentions": {
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            "@type": "ItemList",
            "@id": "itemlist",
            "name": document.querySelector(".bigtitle1").innerText,
            "description": "Puedes caminar desde aquí hasta estas atracciones vecinas",
            "itemListElement": [
          ]
    }
    }
    }
        for (var i =0; i<items.length;++i) {
          var lower = items[i].querySelector("a")
          var desc = items[i].querySelectorAll("p")
          schema["mainEntityOfPage"]["mentions"]["itemListElement"][i]={
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "name":lower.innerText,
            "url":lower.href,
            "description":desc[1].innerText
          } //end of listitem dictionary
        } //end of for loop
        var scrip = document.createElement('script')
        scrip.type = 'application/ld+json'
        scrip.id = 'schemantra'
        scrip.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(schema)
        document.body.appendChild(scrip)
}
    </script>`
```

i tried the code offline, it works but with GTM it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

If your GTM container or trigger is later than `window load`. I guess this code won't fire.

You can remove the `window.onload = function() {}` on the outside. And make the GTM trigger to `window Loaded`.

This might help